# Is there a generic implementation to export list of objects to xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a list of objects `List<T>` and I want to export them to XML file, the issue that these objects are not serializable because they are coming from external dll.

What I am looking for is a method which take the list of objects and generate xml file from it. Is there an implementation for this or should I read by hand each property and put in a xmlelement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to nest a `Select` method in a `new XElement` on this one like so:
(**Note**: You can make this really easy by overloading `ToString` (EDIT: I realize now, you don't have that kind of access. I'll leave it there for anyone else looking for a solution to a similar problem.))

`new XElement("Data", MyList.Select(cl => cl.ToXml() + ","))`

Where "MyList" is your `List<T>` and `ToXml` is you artfully crafted method that spits out the data from each class in the list.

That's the 1 liner approach. If going with this method, all you really need to do is either ignore the trailing comma when loading in the data -OR- you can trim it before leaving the method.

The above will only work *if* there is some really handy output property or method for all the instance data. If that doesn't exist, then you will have to hand write them or you might be able to use reflection. I'm not 100% sure about reflection due to not having used it as of yet.

EDIT: Woohoo! Learning how to use reflection! *And* my computer didn't explode!

Now that that's out of my system, here's another 1-liner that should yield all set property names and values. (**Note**: You really should use some sort of checking in this unless you know with absolute certainty that all the properties that you are getting the values from are indeed set upon construction)

`var output = foo.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(p => p.Name + ", " + p.GetValue(foo, null))`

That yields an `IEnumerable<string>` containing all the property names and their respected values. You should be able to sub `Select(p => new XElement(p.Name, p.GetValue(foo, null)))` in place of the previous line for more direct changing.

DISCLAIMER: If you are going after fields then it should be a simple change from `GetProperties` to `GetFields`.

Comment: great, but as I see it is currently exporting just on item from a list to xml, how to export all list items to xml?

Comment: Ok, I did it using this code:     `var xEle = new XElement("Clients",
                from cl in MYLIST
                select new XElement("Client",cl.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(p => new XElement(p.Name, p.GetValue(cl, null)))));`

Comment: Very good! I was a bit distracted with another project, but congrats on getting it working! The only thing now is to make sure that your coworkers can read and understand all that scribble. :)